# 'v8::Value::ToNumber': was declared deprecated

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node-gyp, deprecation-warning

I'm trying to access a known object and get one of its properties as a `Number`

Unfortunately, the following code...

```
Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate();

Local<Object> opts = args[0]->ToObject();

Local<Number> mode = opts->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "mode"))->ToNumber();
```

is giving the following warning:

> warning C4996: 'v8::Value::ToNumber': was declared deprecated 
>   ....node-gyp\8.5.0\include\node\v8.h(9578): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::ToNumber'

In the v8.h I noticed the comment on `ToNumber`: "Use maybe version". I've attempted to convert it to a `Maybe` but I've not yet been able to get any attempt to compile correctly. What is the correct approach to using `Maybe` and getting the `Number` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the "Use maybe version" comment in the `v8.h` led me in the wrong direction. The deprecate notice seems to apply to the method-overload that is missing the isolate. If you pass the isolate...

```
->ToNumber(isolate);
```

it works without warning.

Comment: But this approach breaks backwards compatibility. i.e. `error C2664: 'bool v8::Value::BooleanValue(void) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'v8::Local<v8::Context>'`